# How can I implement SplitView in another view in MvvmCross?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

[image: sample flow]

How can I achieve this flow using MvvmCross? I went through the N+1 tutorial about SplitView but that uses a single split view as the main controller with a custom presentor.

For my app, it starts with a default presentor & Home is the main screen and I need to show a split view for one of the option. Is this possible using the default UISplitViewController? Or will I need to create a custom control? The user will also need to navigate back to the home screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MvvmCross presenter has really quite a very small interface.

The split view example from [the N=24 video](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n24-splitviewpresenter-n1-days-of.html) is:

```
public class SplitPresenter : MvxBaseTouchViewPresenter
{
    private SplitViewController _svc;

    public SplitPresenter(UIWindow window)
    {
        _svc = new SplitViewController();
        window.RootViewController = _svc;
    }

    public override void Show(Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        var viewController = (UIViewController)Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTouchViewCreator>().CreateView(request);

        if (request.ViewModelType == typeof(FirstViewModel))
            _svc.SetLeft(viewController);
        else
            _svc.SetRight(viewController);
    }
}
```

Since this is just C# interacting with UIKit, then it's very open for users to extend.

For example, you could:

- extend your presenter to include both a navigation controller and a splitview controller and you could then change the RootViewController appropriately during show requests.
- or you could consider pushing your splitviewcontroller as a child of the navigation controller (this would make back easy!)
- or you could consider leaving your splitviewcontroller as the root controller and presenting your login view as a modal display over the top.
- or... really the options are open - this is C# coupled with the power, flexibility and occasional quirks of UIKit

---

One side note: personally, I find that once I start building up more complex UIs, then I often start aggregating the presentation responsibilities. This is shown, for example:

- in the [N=25](https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-25-Tabbed/Tabbed.Touch/Setup.cs#L58) presenter which asks the tab owning view to decide where to show the new view/viewmodel
- in this [opcode blog post](http://enginecore.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/more-dynamic-android-fragments-with.html) where the CustomPresenter maintains a custom list of fragment activity hosts which have registered for various viewmodel requests (when they register and what they subsequently do with those requests is entirely up to them)

because this is just C# it's fairly easy to build up UIs which change from one paradigm (e.g. tabs) to another (e.g. splitView) and where those UIs are well encapsulated - they should kind of look after themselves.

Comment: Thank you so much Stuart. I did it by extending the presenter and switching the RootViewController. Just for your info, the second option doesnt work because Apple does not allow SplitViewController to be pushed on the NavigationController ;) Thanks for all your help!!