# Swap RootViewController with MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I need to implement a login/logout using MVVMCross, iOS only to start. After the user logs in, I want to close the view and make the "real" first view the root controller. For logout, I want to do the same in reverse. Whenever the LoginViewModel is requested, clear the root and replace it.

This [Remove ViewController from stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934748/remove-viewcontroller-from-stack) indicates there is a ClearTop parameter, but it looks like it is gone in v3?

I then found this [What is the best way to handle GoBack for the different MvvmCross (v3) platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157597/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-goback-for-the-different-mvvmcross-v3-platforms) and I implemented this Presenter:

```
        public override void Close(IMvxViewModel toClose)
        {
            if (toClose is LoginViewModel)
            {
                ClearBackStack();
                Show(new MvxViewModelRequest() { ViewModelType = typeof(FirstViewModel)});
                return;
            }
            base.Close(toClose);
        }

        public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {
            if (request.ViewModelType == typeof (LoginViewModel))
            {
                ClearBackStack();
            }
            base.Show(request);
        }
```

Is this the correct way to handle this? Is there an easier mechanism (pre-v3 like)? Should I be overriding ChangePresentation instead?

Also, is there a mechanism to call ShowViewModel from a View? Do I need to resolve the IMvxViewDispatcher or is there a more straight forward method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you want to do custom presentation techniques then the easiest way is to implement your own view presenter.

For an introduction and some links on this, see [How can I implement SplitView in another view in MvvmCross?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720074/how-can-i-implement-splitview-in-another-view-in-mvvmcross)

You are free to write code directly in your views, including navigation logic using resolved IoC objects. However, mvvmCross tries to encourage you to put this logic in the viewmodels - especially so that the 'logic' is more easily shared between platforms.